# Remove site name from template using twig function

Tags: theming, 8

I try to get rid of the site name which come with the twig expresseion `{{ page.header }}`.

To get further details of that variable I enabled twig debug mode and printed it `{{ kint(page.header) }}`.

It seems that `block--system-branding-block.html.twig` is used within `{{ page.header }}`. At the end of file it shows.

```
{% if site_name %}
   <div class="site-name">
      <a href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

The question is how to use a twig function to remove that item from `{{ page.header }}`.
There is a filter which is called `without` and I already applied it to `page.header|without('site_name')`. But that didnt work.

Additional question, how to establish a connection between the printed variables from `{{ kint(...) }}` and the template file. Iam looking for that specific div which displays the site name but I can't find it in the printed variables from debug in order to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the block in the block layout.

If you don't want to do it in the ui, you have to look for the block name. This is probably `sitebranding`.

For example to remove the block with the name `sitebranding` from the region `header` in the page template:

```
{{ page.header|without('sitebranding') }}
```

If you are looking for the site name in the kint print out, it is not always possible to find the actual content early in the templates. Often it is processed at a later stage.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to get it removed on front_page and the without statement plus is_front did the job in the twig template!

Comment: Normally you would do this in the ui. In the block layout you can configure the visibility to not show the block if the page is <front>.